# Unity timer with 2 digit milliseconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have got a timer that works, but I would like it to be formatted like this:

```
0:00:00
```

instead of this

```
0:00:000


public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timeValue = 0;
    public TextMeshProUGUI TimeText;

    private void Update()
    {
        timeValue += Time.deltaTime;
        DisplayTime(timeValue);
    }

    private void DisplayTime(float timeToDisplay)
    {
        float Minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay /60);
        float Seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay % 60);
        float MilleSeconds = timeToDisplay % 1 * 1000;

        TimeText.text = string.Format("{0:0}:{1:00}:{2:00}" , Minutes , Seconds, MilleSeconds);
    }
}
```

I tried to change the format in code from this

```
{0:0}:{1:00}:{2:000}
```

to this

```
{0:0}:{1:00}:{2:00}
```

but it didn't change anything.

Please help

Comment: **Milli**-seconds are - as their name tells you - the thousandth' part of a second. Therefore, you will **always** have values from 000 to 999. Why do you insist on cutting those to just two digits? Doesn't really make any sense ..... if you "truncate" that number to 2 digits, you're really now dealing with **centi-**seconds - the hundredth' part of a second - no longer milliseconds....

Comment: How come you arent using StopWatch https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 0):

Issue will be you probably want the 2 **significant digits**

but in general the milliseconds are e.g. `002` with `ToString("00")` this will will become `02` wich is wrong.

Also e.g. `123` will just stay `123` as the custom formatter [`00`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the-0-custom-specifier) only comes into play when there are **insignificant digits** (in your case leading `0`).

Why not just use and stick to the seconds only and let c# do the rounding etc itself

```
float Minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay /60);
timeToDisplay -= Minutes * 60;
var secondsDisplay = timeToDisplay.ToString("00.00").Replace('.', ':');

TimeText.text = $("{Minutes:0}:{secondsDisplay}");
```

which would do the rounding for you and you then can still decide how many digits you want to show

Answer (score 0):

Using a little maths and casting to `int` you can grab the components of the given time value.

```cs
private void DisplayTime(float timeToDisplay)
{
    // get the total full seconds.
    var t0 = (int) timeToDisplay;

    // get the number of minutes.
    var m = t0/60;

    // get the remaining seconds.
    var s = (t0 - m*60);

    // get the 2 most significant values of the milliseconds.
    var ms = (int)( (timeToDisplay - t0)*100);

    TimeText.text = $"{m:00}:{s:00}:{ms:00}";
}
```

This way you don’t need more strings created than required, especially if this is performed many times a second. And you’re not performing any remainder calculations (`%`), which are often frowned upon.

The code can be trivially extended to include hours (by dividing `t0` by 3600), but that doesn’t seem to be a requirement.